# Ignore username's case in SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Does SpringSecurity have some built-in ability to ignore the letter-case of username? For example, if the username is "student001", then it will accept "Student001" as well as "stUdent001".

The reason I need this is that our system use emails as usernames. Of course I would be able to do this by extending the DAOAuthenticationProvider class, but I just wonder if there's any built-in option exists for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` then I presume you're using the `JdbcDaoImpl` with it, which loads users from a JDBC database.

If so, you can override the SQL query that `JdbcDaoImpl` uses to look up users by manually creating the bean yourself. The default query that Spring Security uses is:

```
select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?
```

You can use the SQL lower function to ignore case:

```
select username,password,enabled from users where lower(username) = lower(?)
```

The appropriate Spring Security XML configuration is:

```
<bean id="org.springframework.security.authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="caseInsensitiveUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="caseInsensitiveUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select username, password, enabled from users where lower(username) = lower(?)" />
</bean>
```

Comment: In [http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-schema.html], the username column is created with **ignorecase**: `username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key`

Comment: That page documents the SQL statements for HSQLDB. Other databases may or may not support `varchar_ignorecase`... for example I use PostgreSQL which does not support it. PostgreSQL does have an add-on `citext` module which does something similar, but it's not installed by default in older versions so adding `lower()` to the query is an easier solution.

Answer (score 4):

I believe any authentication provider take advantage of the UserDetails and UserDetailsService interfaces.

When an implementation of

`UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;`

is given for custom application specific  `UserDetailsService`, we can ignore the case of `username` and provide the `UserDetails` to the spring-security to proceed with further authentication/authorization.

BUT, if spring provided `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl` is used as 
`UserDetailsService` it will load the userdetails from `user` table with condition `"where username=?"`. So it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

[gutch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402033) is partially right. It allows user with JdbcDaoImpl does case-insensitive check with user table. But you will require Authorities table query also needs to be changed.

```
<bean id="caseInsensitiveUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select username, password, enabled from users where lower(username) = lower(?)" />
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select username,authority " +
        "from authorities where lower(username) = lower(?)" />
</bean>
```